# Google Apps Script- Copy & paste data from column one row at a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

(Please note: JavaScript, Stack Overflow posting, & Google Script novice)

THE BACKGROUND: I'm attempting to use a [Google Sheet Email Notification](http://www.emailnotificationaddon.webirdesign.com/index.html#) Add On to trigger notifications when a specific value is seen in a Google Sheet.  The config requirements of the add on look for a TextValue, however it has trouble finding the value in a pivot table (where my data is sorted).  I've tried moving the data to another sheet with a QUERY formula, however the resultant value is not seen by the add on as a TextValue but rather a cell formula.

My workaround to this is to use a script to copy & paste the data from my pivot to a separate sheet.  I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357502/google-apps-script-how-to-copy-a-columns-to-another-sheet-at-next-available#new-answer?newreg=6af6bdc5a11a45aca7ff8d8ca640e30b) as my guide to create my script.  It works, however because it pastes all column values at once, the add on is having trouble identifying the trigger TextValue.

THE QUESTION: instead of having the entire column copied and pasted at once, how can I tweak this script to copy and paste a row at a time with a slight delay (1-2 seconds)?  This delay will allow the add on to see the the target TextValue and execute the notification (I've tested this manually and it works as expected).  Any help in modifying this script (or completely changing the logic if necessary) would be greatly appreciated!!

```
//Copy contents of inventory column daily to run notification add on

function readInventoryNum() {
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory Totals");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Testing123");

// Copy from 2nd row, 7th column, all rows for one column 

var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 7, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//Paste to another sheet from first cell onwards 

sheetTo.getRange(1,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Comment: Why would you slow down your script and use more resources? Just inspect the pasted value array and use the paste offset to identify the A1 notation for the corresponding cell.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations!  @tehhowch, I'm with you, I don't want to make the script inefficient or use up additional resources.  I'm open to exploring your recommendation but I'm not following.  Can you clarify or give some example code (I'm new to all this).

Comment: I would ditch that add-on and write my own notification mailer, where I have explicit control over how and when to construct and send the messages. I mentioned A1 notation as I was imagining the email was something like "so-and-so modified cell 'B59' from X to Y"

Comment: @tehhowch gotcha!  Sounds a little ambitious for my first project so I may suffer through a solution with the 3rd party add on I'm using as v1 and get better educated on MailApp and my JavaScript for V2 down the line.  Thanks for the input!