# Copying and pasting data in Google Sheets to another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dashboard that is reporting live data based on a growing customer database, and I am currently tracking the daily process by copying and pasting the data in the column into the next on a daily basis.

I'd like to create a script that automatically copies the values from an array (B:B) for example, into another sheet OR into the next available column to the right.

You may refer to the image below for further clarity.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTwPc.png)

I saw may threads on this but they were all about copying into a different row, as opposed to a different column.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot understand about `I'd like to create a script that automatically copies the values from an array (B:B) for example, into another sheet OR into the next available column to the right.`. Can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: Hello @HusseinSulaiman, does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357502/google-apps-script-how-to-copy-a-columns-to-another-sheet-at-next-available answer your question?

Comment: @ale13 thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it does kind of answer my question. However, the example shows adding of rows. If i wish to add columns instead, do I change it from "getLastRow()" to "getLastColumn()"

Comment: @Tanaike basically, I wish to populate rows based on daily input from a different sheet. Right now, I am manually copying and pasting the data on a daily basis onto a new column every day. For example, if today's data is pasted into column "B:B", then tomorrow's will be pasted into column "C:C", and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying.

Comment: @HusseinSulaiman, no, you will need the `getLastRow()` in order to be able to identify where does the column end. So I think the solution mentioned in the comment will work just as expected for you - just adjust the ranges accordingly. Have you tried it? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `getLastRow()` method is used to **return the position of the last row that has content**.

The `getLastColumn()` method is used to **return the position of the last column that has content**.

Therefore, in order to be able to copy the data into the next available column, I suggest you try this:

```
function copyColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET");
  var sheetFrom = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET_FROM");
  var sheetTo = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET_TO");
  var values = sheetFrom.getRange(NO_OF_THE_ROW_WHERE_DATA_STARTS, 3, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  sheetTo.getRange(NO_OF_THE_ROW_WHERE_DATA_STARTS,sheetTo.getLastColumn()+1,values.length,1).setValues(values);
}
```

The above script localizes all the data that needs to be copied by using the `getRange()` method and is copied by using `getValues()`.

- `NO_OF_THE_ROW_WHERE_DATA_STARTS` is the value representing the number of the row where your data starts (in your case the row of `No of LP - Secured`);
- `3` is the value representing the `C` column (where the data you want to be copied is located);
- `sheetFrom.getLastRow()` is the value representing the end of the data you want to be copied;
- `1` is the value representing the number of columns that need to be copied.

Afterwards, the `getRange()` method is used again in order to be able to identify where the data needs to be pasted and `setValues()` in order to actually paste it.

**Note:** The above script works for different spreadsheets and/or different sheets OR for sheets in the same spreadsheet. If you want to use it for the latter case, you just have to put the name of your sheet instead of `SHEET_FROM` and `SHEET_TO`.

Moreover, I suggest you check the following links since they might be of help:

1. [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
2. [Range Class Apps Script - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
3. [Range Class Apps Script - setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);
4. [Sheet Class Apps Script - getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn);
5. [Sheet Class Apps Script - getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow);